# Difference between variable which keeps function and function itself

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why I have to use the variable `keepScore` to make my code works.
After delete var I would write:

```js
questions[n].checkAnswer(parseInt(answer), score())
```

but then point amount could be only `0` or `1` - `var sc=0` execute every cycle.
Then what is the difference between these two codes?

```js
function score() {
  var sc = 0;
  return function (correct) {
    if (correct) sc++;
    return sc;
  }
}
var keepScore = score();           //here


function nextQuestion() {

  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
  questions[n].displayQuestion();

  var answer = prompt('Please select the correct answer.');

  if (answer !== 'exit') {
    questions[n].checkAnswer(parseInt(answer), keepScore);    //here

    nextQuestion();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `score` is a function that returns a function. The outer function's variables are baked into the inner function (this is called a closure). The purpose of doing that here is to allow the variable `sc` to be used by the inner function but not be available to other functions. It is essentially a way to hide that variable. This is a common JavaScript idiom (you can use it in other languages, but I see it a lot more in JavaScript than in any other language—in fact, there's a related pattern given a special name: the [immediately-invoked function expression](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-iife/)).

The variable `keepScore` holds a reference to the function that `score()` returns, so when you call `keepScore` you are really calling that function. Since you only call `score()` once, `sc` is initialized to zero only once, and `keepScore()` increments it.

I have to wonder... if you don't know what it's doing, why did you write it that way?

Comment: Hope this helps to understand closure better - https://medium.com/dailyjs/i-never-understood-javascript-closures-9663703368e8

Comment: After yours explanations it got clear in my mind. Thanks a lot. The article was also very helpful !

Answer (score 0):

This is because every time you run the `score` function you get a function returned that has a context with it (the variable `sc`) which gets initialized to zero for each call to `score`.  When you call it once and keep the function in a variable, then you have one function that gets repeatedly called with one context and `sc` can increment.

You could get away without the variable if you pull the `sc` variable outside of the scope of the `score` function like this:

```js
var sc = 0;
function score() {
  return function(correct) {
    if (correct) sc++;
    return sc;
  }
}
```

But then of course it begs the question - why bother with a function that returns a function at all? You could do this instead:

```js
var sc = 0;
function score(correct) {
  if (correct) sc++;
  return sc;
}

// then later pass the function as a reference
questions[n].checkAnswer(parseInt(answer), score);
```